# Error with Windows Phone Emulator

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, xna-4.0

I am trying to get my windows phone development up and running again.

I am having serious issues with the emulator where it looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNT81.jpg

Here is my info. Running windows 8 on a computer with quad core proc and good video card.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Emulator looks this way after startup or after launching XNA app?

Comment: What version of WP SDK you have installed ? Windows 8 compatibility was added only in 7.1.1

Answer (score 1):

This page might help:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wptools/thread/5b659eea-9a4f-45ce-8418-b9097d586197/

> Emulator Video appears corrupted running XNA or Silverlight + XNA
>   game.  The emulator images included in Windows Phone SDK 7.1.1 have a
>   compatability problem with some video cards or video card drivers. The
>   problem appears as corrupted display when using the XNA graphics
>   rendering engine in landscape orientation when system tray is visible.
>
> To work around this problem:   XNA games should either set the
>   orientation to portrait:
>       graphicsDeviceManager.SupportedOrientations = DisplayOrientation.Portrait;
>
> -or- enable full screen mode:
>       graphicsDeviceManager.IsFullScreen = true;
>
> Silverlight + XNA games which use landscape page orientation should
>   disable the system tray:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage  
    SupportedOrientations="Landscape" Orientation="LandscapeLeft" 
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False"
```