# Windows Phone 7 emulator on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone-7.1.1

I followed [this "guide"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2012/02/29/10274694.aspx) to make my Windows Phone SDK 7.1.1 work on my Windows 8 Pro 32 bit.

Everything works perfectly but when i run the application the emulator appears and after 30 s appears a message error "Windows phone emulator has stopped working".

I have 2 Gb of ram and I don't think this is the problem because on my desktop (I'm on the notebook) I have 1,5 Gb of ram (w7) and all works fine.

So what's the problem ?

I really need to make Windows phone sdk run on this notebook !
Thank you all and sorry for my bad english :S

Comment: Have you instaled the oficial sdk? Are you running with the visual studio?

Comment: Ye, i have installed the sdk and the 7.1.1 both from the official website. what do you mean for  "With the visual studio?" i have also installed visual studio SP1 but when i run the application i only have Microsoft visual studio express for Windows phone open

Comment: okay, you run only a hello wolrd?

Comment: Nono i only create a new project and then run it

Comment: uhn...you did read thats: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11834736/error-with-windows-phone-emulator  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/be73ddc6-4116-4552-aca7-7332a19d4601/   because can for your configuration (anti-virus or landscape)

Comment: I have no one of this error, but tried to disable the antivirus but nothing worked for me..uff ://

Comment: uhn... sorry, I dont know... you can to reinstall...